# Is there a way to use the enum ordinal in a foreach in MyBatis

Tags: java, xml, mybatis

I'm trying to filter a select-query with mybatis dynamically in a foreach loop.

Here's an example from my xml mapper:

```
<if test="array!= null and array.length > 0">
   AND arrayValCol IN
      <foreach item="item" collection="array" separator="','" open="('" close="')">
         ${item}
      </foreach>
</if>
```

But the array contains enums as values and I'm couldn't find any solution in the mybatis documentation or with google.

Is there a way to solve this at all?

Comment: `Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values())` or such?

Comment: I have no problem with filling an array. My problem is that mybatis does not map the enum to its ordinal in the foreach loop.

Comment: `${item.ordinal()}`?

Answer (score 1):

- By default, MyBatis uses [`EnumTypeHandler`](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/type/EnumTypeHandler.java) which calls `name()` method when binding enum parameters. You need to tell MyBatis to use [`EnumOrdinalTypeHandler`](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/type/EnumOrdinalTypeHandler.java) instead.
- You should use `#{}` instead of `${}` whenever possible. See the [FAQ](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-).

```xml
<if test="array!= null and array.length > 0">
  AND arrayValCol IN
  <foreach item="item" collection="array" separator="," open="(" close=")">
    #{item,typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler}
  </foreach>
</if>
```

It is also possible to change the default enum type handler by specifying [`defaultEnumTypeHandler`](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#settings) in configuration.

```xml
<settings>
  <setting name="defaultEnumTypeHandler"
    value="org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler"/>
</settings>
```